# How to best filter a MongoDB collection using a predicate

Tags: mongodb, filter, predicate

We would like to filter a MongoDB collection using an "overspecified" find() query. For example: `collection A`, the collection we want to filter, has documents that contain a set of requirements for attributes. Examples are the document `a`, which contains the requirement `{req: age:{min:20,max:30}}` and `b` which contains the requirement `{req: gender:male}`.

We also have a document, `d`, from `collection D` that contains the following attributes: `d = {age:21, gender: male}`.

In this case, both `a` and `b` should be in the set of documents that `d` is eligible for, as `d` fulfills the requirements for both.

However, if we include all of `d`'s attributes in a `find` query, we get `db.A.find({d.age > req.age.min, d.age < req.age.max, d.gender: req.gender})`, which would exclude both `a` and `b` from our result.

What is the best way to select all the documents in `A` that `d` fulfills the requirements for, given that `d` may contain more attributes than the requirements of a document in A specify, and that the requirements in `A` and attributes in `D` are not fixed? We would like to avoid specifying every possible attribute in `D` in all `A.req` documents as we would like our requirements to be as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no straightforward ways to do this. The only route you can take is performing an existence check on each requirement which doesn't result in the most elegant queries imaginable. Using your query format :

```
db.A.find({$and:[{req.age.min:{$exists:true}}, {d.age > req.age.min}], ....)
```

In other words. You modify your query so it follows "if D's attribute has a requirement in A check if it meets that requirement". Frankly I think looking at a more appropriate schema might be a more elegant route though.